# Spring boot post HTTP Request

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

Hi i have problem with my app. I am using Spring Boot/Rest and when i trying execute request HTTP i get error in console. Request method 'POST' not supported. GET working fine but POST not... and i don't know what i can do more This is my controller code.

```
@Controller
@RestController
public class MessageController {

@RequestMapping("/getMessages")
public List<Messages> getMessages(@RequestParam(value="id", defaultValue="1")int id){


    DB db = new DB();       

    List<Messages> messages;

    try {
        messages = db.getMessages(id);
        System.out.println("Pobieram wiadomosci: "+messages.size());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        messages = null;
    }   

    return messages;

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/setMessage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void checkUser(@RequestBody @Valid final Messages message) {

    DB db = new DB();

    try {
        System.out.println("Message:"+message.getText()+" idUser:"+message.getUser());
        db.setMessage(message.getRoom(), message.getText(), message.getUser().getId());
        System.out.println("Wysyłam wiadomosc");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Post the error message you get the console. Also let me know the URL of the HTTP request that you are trying to request.

Comment: The error is "Request method 'POST' not supported" and the URL is "http://localhost:8080/setMessages"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http://localhost:8080/setMessages` is not mapped in the controller.

Change the URL to `http://localhost:8080/setMessage`

Or change the mapping as this:

`@RequestMapping(value = "/setMessages", method = RequestMethod.POST)`

Answer (score -1):

The URL is not correct mapping is wrong, use http://localhost:8080/setMessage in the client
For more details watch:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7j6mLXlJ2YI&list=PLeaW10A6uFKMOMcmGp35yLbduIyQEcBj4&index=6

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of the 24 minute video in text?